# Тестирование Python

Tags: python, testng

Требуется тестировать программы со множественным input и print. Например

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
print(a + b)
c = int(input())
print(a + b +c )
```

Как можно при тестирование подобных задач программно вводить input и получать выводы c print и ошибки

Comment: обязателен `input`?

Comment: Для тестирования обычно ввод-вывод выносят из кода. В коде должны быть только переменные на входе функции, при тестировании туда просто подставляются разные значения. При реальной работе делаете `input`-ы снаружи функции и передаёте что они получили уже в функцию.

Comment: @CrazyElf Эти задачи сдаются студентами не в виде функций, а в таком виде как в примере. Требуется сделать что бы данный в инпут вводились или тогда заменялись из теста в тест. Как тогда сделать автоматическую замену при тесте?

Comment: @Violet Обязатель input и обязателен print

Comment: А операционка какая? По идее можно заменить `stdin`, `stdout` и `stderr` в строке вызова скрипта, чтобы ввод из файла был и выводилось всё тоже в файл. Но в линуксе и в винде это по-разному немного вроде делается.

Comment: @CrazyElf Пока Windows. Мне главное понять что именно делать и как, а потом я переделаю под сервер

Comment: Попробуйте перенаправить потоки так: `script.py < infile.txt > outfile.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @CrazyElf нашёл более легкий способ. Использование модуля subprocess. Но спасибо за помощ